# How to block entering decimal values ​in qty in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have set in all products:
Qty uses decimal => 0

but on each product I can add example 1.4 product.
I'm using Magento 2.2.8, my input in addtocart.phtml file looks like this:

```
    <div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                <div class="field qty">
                    <div class="control">

                        <input type="number"
                               name="qty"
                               id="qty"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')); ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')); ?>"
                               data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                               data-mage-init='{"quantitySpinner": {}}'
                               value="1"
                               aria-valuenow="1"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: do you want to block or allow only decimals ?

Comment: @OBAID I want to block, this applies to all products in stock